# Merging a GIT repo

Tags: git

I have a GIT repo setup on my laptop; it is totally local as it pushes to another local hard drive on the same laptop, instead of a server online.

Recently, my laptop was sent back for servicing, so I copied my project code manually over to a desktop and continued working from there.

Now that my laptop is back now, is there a way to "merge" the code from my desktop to the older code in my laptop? By merge, I mean to preserve both the history of changes from both my older repo (laptop) and newer repo (desktop) to form one continuous timeline of changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull from your desktop. If you can access your desktop via ssh you can just add it as another repo to your laptop:

```
laptop$ git remote add desktop username@desktop_ip_address:path/to/repo
```

Then you can pull:

```
laptop$ git pull desktop
```

Pulling is simple and can be done between any git repo. It's what "pull request" on github is all about: pulling changes from someone else's repo into your repo. Pushing is a bit more complicated because of potential merge conflicts. That's why it's not recommended to push to a non-bare repo.

See the docs for more info: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way. First commit all local changes on both repos. Then from your desktop repo:

```
git fetch <laptop repo>
git pull <laptop repo>
git push <laptop repo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git stash` from your laptop repo then run a `git pull` from your laptop to pull down the changes you made on your desktop. From there you can run `git stash pop` and finally fix any merge conflicts if need be. Here is some documentation on `git stash`

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash